# iOS - present ABUnknownPersonViewController from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, addressbookui

I'm trying to present ABUnknownPersonViewController from tabbarcontroller.
As i understand ABUnknownPersonViewController works only in navigationcontroller.

What can i do to walk around this situation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you would want to do that. From a UI perspective, a tab really isn't the right location for a 'new contact' view. That said, I did run into something similar when trying to use an ABUnknownPersonViewController in a popover. The solution is to programmatically add the ABUnknownPersonViewController as a childViewController of your tab controller. Here is a step by step guide:

1. Create a custom UIViewController class that implements ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate.
2. In the storyboard find the tab view you want to display the ABController in and assign your custom class as its controller.
3. In the viewDidLoad method of your controller class, add the following code:

```objective-c
ABUnknownPersonViewController *picker =[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];    
picker.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;    
picker.displayedPerson = aContact;
picker.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
picker.allowsActions = YES;        
[self addChildViewController:picker];
picker.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```